# error while uploading kaggle.json file in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, kaggle

I am finding issue while uploading kaggle.json file in google colab, with following command
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

error :

```
*MessageError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-21dc3c638f66> in <module>()
      1 from google.colab import files
----> 2 uploaded = files.upload()
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/_message.py in read_reply_from_input(message_id, timeout_sec)
```

104         reply.get('colab_msg_id') == message_id):
    105       if 'error' in reply:
--> 106         raise MessageError(reply['error'])
    107       return reply.get('data', None)
    108 
    MessageError: TypeError: Cannot read property '_uploadFiles' of undefined*